# Android - Parse Query - need to know if a string is contained within one of multiple columns in my database table

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I have an Android application using parse as a backend. One of my tables in my parse database contains groups of users, one row in this table contains 6 columns of users to form one group.
I would like to return each row where the current user is contained in one of the columns.
My question is what is the most optimum way of achieving this?
As it stands I can think of two ways:
1. query each row in the groups table and loop through each cloumn looking for the current users username.
2. if possible - use a parse query that says if currenUser equals member 1 or member 2 or member 3 or member 4 or member 5 or member 6. But I don't know if this is possible

Any pointers or help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `ParseQuery<ParseObject> query` object a `whereEqualTo` method is available `query.whereEqualTo(key, value);` try using your `column name` in place or `key` and your desired value in in place of `value`.
Using this you will only get the rows which contains your desired values. It just works as the `where` clause in SQL qyery. so you will not need to iterate over all the DB entries.

Comment: Would this only return rows where the desired value is in the specified column? I would like to look in multiple columns

Comment: try putting where conditions twice or thrice like query.whereEqualTo(key1, value1); , query.whereEqualTo(key2, value2); , query.whereEqualTo(key3, value3);

Comment: I did not realise you could put .whereEqualTo multiple times in one query

Comment: Sorry I'm new to databases and parse

Comment: No issues.. always happy to help :)